# Multiple getJSON requests and element order

Tags: jquery, json

The set below runs 4 JSON requests then created a div to get prepended to another div. But I cannot seem to get the order of the items to be consistent. I know it's because there are multiple requests and they load at different times, but I can't figure out how to combine all the requests and pass the variables. If I could get all the requests in the same statement I could just make one large prepend, but I can't seem to get the variables correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ( $('#main_intranet-main').length ) {
      $.getJSON("xxx", function(data) {
        var bibs = data[0].n;
var bibs2 = data[1].n;


        $('div#news1').prepend('<div class="newsitem" id="mystats"><table class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%; background: none;"><thead><th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; padding: 8px; line-height: 1.42857143; vertical-align: middle; text-transform: uppercase;">Patrons added and expired yesterday</thead><tbody><tr><td><strong>New Patrons</strong></td><td><strong>Expired Patrons</strong></td></tr><tr><td><center>' + bibs + '</center></td><td><center>' + bibs2 + '</center></td></tbody></table></div>');

});

    }



    if ( $('#main_intranet-main').length ) {
      $.getJSON("xxx", function(data) {
        var items = data[0].n;


        $('div#news1').prepend('<div class="newsitem" id="mystats"><table class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%; background: none;"><thead><th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; padding: 8px; line-height: 1.42857143; vertical-align: middle; text-transform: uppercase;">Items Checked Out Yesterday</thead><tbody><tr><td><center>' + items + ' </center></td></tbody></table></div>');

});

    }

    if ( $('#main_intranet-main').length ) {
      $.getJSON("xxx", function(data) {
        var house = data[0].totalcount;


        $('div#news1').prepend('<div class="newsitem" id="mystats"><table class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%; background: none;"><thead><th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; padding: 8px; line-height: 1.42857143; vertical-align: middle; text-transform: uppercase;">In House Use Yesterday</thead><tbody><tr><td><center>' + house + ' </center></td></tbody></table></div>');

});

    }

    if ( $('#main_intranet-main').length ) {
      $.getJSON("xxx", function(data) {
        var bibs = data[0].Total;
var bibs2 = data[1].Total;
var total = bibs - bibs2


        $('div#news1').prepend('<div class="newsitem" id="mystats"><table class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%; background: none;"><thead><th colspan="3" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; padding: 8px; line-height: 1.42857143; vertical-align: middle; text-transform: uppercase;">Net Patrons YTD</thead><tbody><tr><td><center>' + total + '</center></td></tr></tbody></table></div>');

});

    }
});
```

Comment: Avoid Jquery Ajax calls if possible. You should use Fetch these days and Promises to make things a LOT simpler, otherwise you're going to need a REALLY dumb closure to make sure everything resolved before continuing on, and Promises wrap that up easily

Comment: Note that you are prepending 4 `div`s each with the same `id`; that's not legal HTML.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the problem. I plan on cleaning all that up once I solve the prepend order issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use the newer [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and `Promise.all` to recieve them all in a specific order:

```
Promise.all([
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100, 1)),
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 2)),
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10, 3))
]).then(([a,b,c]) => console.log(c,b,a))
```

After about 1 second, this code will log all of the values to the console in reverse order, dynamically de-referenced.

More information on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

---

A more curated example:

```
Promise.all([
  !($(selector1).property.length) ? null : Fetch('xxx1').then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : null),
  !($(selector2).property.length) ? null : Fetch('xxx2').then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : null),
  !($(selector3).property.length) ? null : Fetch('xxx3').then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : null),
]).then(([a,b,c]) => console.log(c,b,a))
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's time to learn the in's and out's of Promise.

Comment: They aren't actually that bad, but their explanations are AWFUL in most places.

Comment: But that's because to explain this without Promises requires a Function, with three sub functions, and a wait loop with a resolving function. Promises take all of those functions, and shove them into 4 lines of code for you

Comment: @T.J. updated with something that might help a little more

Comment: Appreciate it, I hope I can figure all this out!

Comment: Goodluck! If you need more help, there's PLENTY of question in regards to Fetch and Promises. But once you learn them you probably won't ever go back to $Ajax and it's bugs

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sequence of `div`'s, one for each *newsitem*, so you can send each to the correct one, and the order in which you send them won't matter.

Comment: I've been trying to but I can't seem to pass the variables correctly. I can only seem to get them to work if they are wrapped in each getJSON statement.